# RSpec redirect_to and return vs. redirect_to && return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a controller that redirects at certain points under certain conditions. When I pass parameters to my spec helper methods in my controller spec (using the latest RSpec) to trigger these conditions I get a

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate
```

error. Under closer examination when I am supposed to redirect I do a line like the following:

```
redirect_to root_path && return
```

And then an exception is thrown in my test suite. I put a break point in the index function of the controller that should be called (that the route I'm redirecting to is pointing to) and it is never called in my test suite. This code seems to work when I just run it in my development environment and on production but for this test it just won't budge. Any ideas?

My test looks something like this:

```
describe TestController do
  it 'redirects properly with failure' do
    get :create, provider: 'test', error: 'access_denied'
    expect(response.body).to match 'test'
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Update!

It seems that changing my redirect to

```
redirect_to root_path and return
```

works in RSpec.

I do not know why the precedence of the `&&` operator is breaking the spec. Does anyone have an explanation of what is going on here?

Comment: can you share the full error message? what's the name of the missing template?

Comment: For this example it would be TestController#create is missing. TestController should be doing a redirect though within itself to another controller (IndexController#public). When I put a pry there though it never gets hit and the RSpec test just fails.

Comment: Please accept an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [the Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

> Make sure to use `and return` instead of `&& return` because `&& return` will not work due to the operator precedence in the Ruby Language.

If you prefer to use `&&`, enclose the arguments to `render` in parentheses:

```
redirect_to(root_path) && return
```

Answer (score 6):

The difference`&&` has higher [precedence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) than `and`. The high precedence results in ruby parsing this as

```
redirect_to(root_path && return)
```

Methods must of course evaluate their arguments before the method itself is called, so in this case `redirect_to` is never called, because ruby hits the `return` first.

On the other hand, the lower precedence of `and` means that it is parsed as

```
(redirect_to root_path) and return
```

Which is what you wanted - first do the redirect and then return.

Answer (score 1):

The template must exist when you test your controller since **views are stubbed by default.** See the [RSpec Documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/views-are-stubbed-by-default)

So make sure you have the template present for your controller action.

Comment: The template is present though for the controller that the redirect goes to. This controller really has no need for templates, it just handles a request and then redirects to another controller which renders the appropriate view.

Answer (score 1):

The default controller spec doesn't follow a redirect. Therefore your index action is never called. Instead you should check if it received the correct redirect order from the server:

```
describe TestController do
  it 'redirects properly with failure' do
    get :create,
        provider: 'test',
        error: 'access_denied'
    expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

This is called test isolation: You only test that the create action redirects to a specific point. How the index action really works should be tested in the controller's index specs rather than the create specs.

Comment: Same error:    Failure/Error: get :create,
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template test_controller/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
         * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x007fa85198a570>"

Answer (score 0):

The answers explaining the different operator precedence of `&&` and `and` are correct as far as they go. However, **the whole idea of checking the return value of `render` or `redirect_to` is misleading and the Rails guide shouldn't recommend it**.

`render` and `redirect_to` are called for their side effects (they modify the response), not for their return values. If they have errors, they raise exceptions, not return falsy values. So it's misleading to use `&&` or `and` at all. Instead, do

```
redirect_to root_path
return
```

to make it clear to readers how the code works and avoid all this fussing with operators.